# Use console.log'd object

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm calling:

```
console.log(some_random_object);
```

…to which Chrome is helpfully dumping the object into the console. This is nice, as I can see alot of useful stuff, but sometimes I want to actually *use* that object, to see how it responds to something, right there in the console.

Is there any way to assign a previously `console.log`'d object to a variable, so that I can start messing with it?

Comment: I usually just set a global variable and access it from the browser's console. Something like `window.myVariable = {my:"object"};`

Answer (score 2):

Using a wrapper for the `console.log()`:

```
function log() {
    window.logHistory = window.logHistory || [];
    if (console) {
        window.logHistory.push(arguments);
        console.log.apply(console, arguments);
    }
}

log("Test");
log({
    test: 1,
    team: "Abc"
});
log(window.logHistory);​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pratik136/DY4Sk/

---

**Output:**

[image]